# Need to query splunk using rest api call and pull mean and stdev

Tags: splunk

I am trying to query using Rest API on splunk with the following:

`curl -u "<user>":"<pass>" -k https://splunkserver.com:8089/services/search/jobs/export -d'search=search index%3d"<index_name" sourcetype%3d"access_combined_wcookie" starttime%3d06/02/2013:0:0:0 endtime%3d06/10/2013:0:0:0  uri_path%3d"<uri1>" OR uri_path%3d"<uri2>" user!%3d"-" referer!%3d"-" | eval Time %3d request_time_length%2f1000000 | stats stdev%28Time%29 as stdev, mean%28Time%29 as mean, count%28uri_path%29 as count by uri_path'`

However I do not get the computed mean and stdev, I only see count. How can I add the mean and stdev?

Answer (score 0):

The query looks about right. I tried a similar query on my end it seemed to give me all 3 aggregates. Only thing I can think of is to make sure you have events that match the search criteria. It could be your time boundaries. Try expanding those or maybe removing one/both of them to see if you get any data for mean and stdev.

Comment: It turns out I needed to query the application configured on Splunk rather than the index. Apparently the app contains specific configurations that allow the mean and stddev to work. I now can get the mean information